# Using Sphinx with MVC and MYSQL on Windows

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, sphinx

I am having problems understanding how to tie all of these together.  My current setup is an MVC website that calls a MYSQL Routine Through the .NET Mysql Connector.  The routine used a full-text search on an innodb table.  This worked wonderful until the full text search started to have around 250k records.  I am looking to move to Sphinx but there isn't a whole lot of info for windows.  Could someone explain how they would all connect?  Would mvc call mysql for common stuff such as login, etc.. but use a different connector and call sphinx when the user searches?  Or would it still call a mysql routine which then calls sphinx itself?  Also, is SphinxSE table type an easier option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory SphinxSE would provide an easy way to query. Your application would just connect to mysql and run a query. It could join the results of the full-text search directly with the data tables and get all the data needed in once go - even sorted right :)

(SphinxSE under the hood would do the seperate connection to Sphinx to run FT search)

But SphinxSE is not always easy install. I've little experience of SphinxSE or windows based mysel/sphinx.

--

Instead yes, you could just have the application connect to sphinx, retrieve a list of document id's, then in turn contact mysql for the actual data. Performing a virtual 'join' in application code, merging the sorted doc-id list and the data from mysql. I've done this in PHP, should be relativly easy in c# too. Just need a specially crafted SQL query (using doc_id in (...) ) and resorting the mysql results.

Sphinx itself should work on Windows pretty well.

--

An alternative might be switch to MariaDB, as that bundles SphinxSE, it might be an easyish solution, but personally just having the application connect to both sphin and mysql is nto that hard.

... in short use SphinxSE if its easy and available. But dont go to all the trouble to get SphinxSE (either via mariaDB or directly) running specifically.

Comment: i ended up having to retrieve document ids and use mysql for the actual data.  Still MUCH MUCH faster than mysql full-text.